# myButton.frame not available why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i have a button when i try to write myButton. then if I click esc button there is not options or any intelligent result.

thanks

Comment: Depends on your code, sometimes the autocomplete just doesn't work. But most likely you have a syntax error before your myButton.fr

Comment: Please try to rephrase that and tell us more about what you expect and things like that... as it is right now, I don't understand what you're asking, I'm afraid.

Comment: thank u all yes the problem was from the previous writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your code look like this?

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController {
    UIBUtton *myButton;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton

@end;

@implementation myViewController

@synthesize myButton;

- (void) someMethod
{
    //Use myButton Here?
    CGRect r = myButton.frame;
}

@end
```

Or This:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController {
    // No need to declare myButton for iPhone or Mac 64-bit
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton

@end;

@implementation myViewController

@synthesize myButton;

- (void) someMethod
{
    //Use myButton Here?
    CGRect r = self.myButton.frame;
}

@end
```

if it's the latter, `myButton` isn't the private variable - only the property.